# Accordion Effect slides up but wont slide down problem using Next.js/React.js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, accordion

using next.js I made a custom accordion the slide moves up and out when the button is clicked successfully. But when its suppose to move back down and into the content it doesnt move down with animation. But instead pastest itself into the DOM directly.

Here is what I tried

Here is some of the relevant code
JS FILE

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import styles from "NEXT.JS FROM A CSS FILE BELOW SHOWING THE CSS CODE";

const AsideCheckout = (props) => {
    const [accordionClick, setAccordionClick] = useState(false);
    const asideRef = useRef(null);

    const slideInAside = (e) => {
        setAccordionClick(!accordionClick);

        if (accordionClick !== false) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                asideRef.current.style.display = "none"; // works when the slide slides up and out i remove it with display none and the content below pushes itself up
            }, 400);
        }

        if (accordionClick !== true) {
            asideRef.current.style.display = "block"; // some how doesn't slide in from the top just pastes itself on the DOM THE PROBLEM
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        asideRef.current.style.display = "none"; // initial launch making it display none
    }, []);

return (
<>
         <div className={styles.aside_accordion_button} onClick={slideInAside}>
            <button>CLICK</button>
         </div>
         <aside ref={asideRef} className={[styles.aside_checkout, accordionClick === true && styles.aside_show_checkout].join(" ")}>
           ... aside content etc
         </aside>
</>
)
}
```

CSS CODE

```
    .aside_checkout {
        grid-column: 1;
        grid-row: -2;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        transform: translateY(-100%);
        transition: transform 0.7s ease-in-out;
        /* display: none; commented out doing this in js */
    }

    .aside_show_checkout {
        transform: translateY(0);
        /* display: block; commented out doing this in js */
        transition: transform 0.7s ease-out;
    }

    .aside_accordion_button {
        grid-row: -3; // THIS IS THE BUTTON placed above the aside content with grid-row -3
        display: flex;
/* some of the properties emitted here CUZ not RELEVANT */
    }
```

So it slides up and out for `transform translateY(-100%)` without a problem. And when I want to slide it backdown with this code for `translateY(0)` it does not slide in from the top instead pastest itself on the page

Answer (score 0):

## **Managed to fix it**

inside this if blocks for the slideInAside function I used setTimeout as I think I need to slowdown React a bit and the time was 0 ZERO

```
    const slideInAside = (e) => {
        setAccordionClick(!accordionClick);
     
        // from here
        if (accordionClick !== false) {
            asideRef.current.classList.remove(styles.aside_show_checkout); // removing it here instead than having it in JSX
            setTimeout(() => {
                asideRef.current.style.display = "none"; // works when the slide slides up and out i remove it with display none and the content below pushes itself up
            }, 400);
        }

        if (accordionClick !== true) {
            asideRef.current.style.display = "block"; // some how doesn't slide in from the top just pastes itself on the DOM THE PROBLEM

// needed to add the setTimeout like this as I think React needs to be slowdown

            setTimeout(() => {
                asideRef.current.classList.add(styles.aside_show_checkout); // adding it here inside the setTimeout instead than having it in JSX
            }, 0);
        }
    }
```

then inside the JSX I removed this

```
         <aside ref={asideRef} className={[styles.aside_checkout, accordionClick === true && styles.aside_show_checkout].join(" ")}>
           ... aside content etc
         </aside>
```

TO JUST

```
         <aside ref={asideRef} className={styles.aside_checkout}> // JUST the main class
           ... aside content etc
         </aside>
```